# Assesment of a production network in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, production, chaincode

I have some questions regarding the deployment of a HLF use case. Suppose we build a platform in which users sell items. The users and their items are stored on the ledger via chaincode. The purpose is to also enforce access control on the items via the chaincode, so that another user for example cannot see a specific item. Then the 2 options regarding the whole identity management are:

1. The users do not have certificates in Fabric, and all transactions made by the users are forwarded to a single registered Client who interacts with the chaincode. Therefore, the transaction context will always have this client's ID. So from my point of view the username should be always passed to each transaction and implement access control using this username, though a registered Client has full authority over their data.
2. Every user is registered and enrolled and have their own identity. Every user makes a transaction directly on the blockchain via the chaincode, and access control can be implemented easily by using the stub.ID() and other attributes. That would mean that >100k users would be registered on a CA or multiple CAs.

The questions are:

1. Is HLF intended and suitable for the 2nd option, or is it made solely for the purpose of interaction between clients of organizations?
2. Is there a best way to handle this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ledger stores facts about the history of transactions that led to the current state of an object. The history also stores the users responsible for the current state of the object. If the state of an object is being changed, the admin/authorized user of an organization must be able to see who performed that change.

In the first approach, if you want to see the details of the user doing the "transaction", you'll have to store it somewhere different from the blockchain. While that can be a use-case of your project, it defeats the purpose of storing all facts about the history of a transaction of an object as every time the same user would be doing the transaction.

The second approach fulfills all the motives of incorporating blockchain in a project. Sure, you'll have to register and enroll every user who's creating/modifying an asset but then Access Control Management can be done in a better way. Please read about [ACL](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/access_control.html) to know about the granular access you can achieve in Hyperledger Fabric.

Also, you can also encode some information about a user in its x509 certificate with ASN.1

Answer (score 0):

Second option is more preferred and Hyperledger Fabric ca could handled number of user registrations. There is Attribute access control also available which you can use at chaincode level to control use access.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CAXRMJ-quhg